# Java signing XML File - prevent standard XML signature namespace inside signature

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, digital-signature

I'm signing an XML File where I'm using the Java XML Digital Signature API, available from Java 6 up to now. 
Web-Source: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/dig-signature-api-140772.html

The Signature looks like following:

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">[...]</Signature>
```

Now I want to know, is there any way, to sign the XML File, to prevent the API to determine this `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"`inside my tag, so that I just have following:

```
<Signature>...</Signature>
```

I'm very thankful for any clues.

Thank you @Vadim for your answer. Lets give more details for my problem. I got a XML Structure like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<tests xmlns="schema1">
<test>
</test>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
</Signature>
</tests>
```

How can I get this working? Because in a third party system I Need to check it against a Schema, where I define the structure of the signature by myself, so there should be like two xmlns inside my

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per XML standard you have to have namespace defined for `<Signature>` element, so  it can be as you have it or outside on parent element with prefix. As

```
 <rootElemnt xmlns:sig="http://....">
     <sig:Signature>....
```

But, why it bother you? Without it `<Signature>` tag belongs to default namespace of parent element and not to proper Signature namespace.

UPDATED If you have two namespaces you have to have two xmlns declarations. One can be default second must have prefix. or both must have prefixes.

If your custom elements are in `xmlns="schema1"`, I think you need to look either how to make `<sig:Signature xmlns:sig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">` or

```
<sch1:tests xmlns:sch1="schema1">
  <sch1:test>
  </sch1:test>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
     ...
     <sch1:customElement>...</sch1:customElement>
  </Signature>
</sch1:tests>
```

It depends on how you build full XML. Sorry, I'do not know how to do that in Java XML Digital Signature API (never used it directly, just through WSDL policy), but all other tools have an ability to handle namespace prefixes

also it can look like:

```
<tests xmlns="schema1">
  <test>
  </test>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
     ...
     <sch1:customElement xmlns:sch1="schema1">...</sch1:customElement>
  </Signature>
</tests>
```

Perhaps it should look like that by defualt, but if not I guess if you marshal `customElement` into XML separately and then add it into Signature it must be like that.

Comment: Thank you @Vadim maybe you could have a look at my additions